# `componentWillReceiveProps` explanation

Tags: reactjs

I recently wanted to upgrade my knowledge of [React](https://reactjs.org/), so I started from the component lifecycle methods. The first thing that got me curious, is this [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops). So, the docs are saying that it's fired when component is receiving new (not necessarily updated) props. Inside that method we can compare them and save into the state if needed.

My question is: Why do we need that method, if changes in props of that component (inside parent `render`) will trigger the re-render of this child component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One common use case are state (`this.state`) updates that may be necessary in response to the updated props.

Since you should not try to update the component's state via `this.setState()` in the `render` function, this needs to happen in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: But how about a `constructor` method than? We compose the state there, so the next time when component props will change in parent `render` function, component will re-render and constructor will be executed again?

Comment: No, the constructor will only be executed when the component instance is initally created.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if some prop is used as a parameter to some fetch function you should watch this prop in `componentWillReceiveProps` to re-fetch data using the new parameter.

Usually `componentDidMount` is used as a place where you trigger a method to fetch some data. But if your container, for example, UserData is not unmounted and you change `userId` prop, the container needs to fetch data of a user for corresponding userId.

```
  class UserData extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.getUser(this.props.userId);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      if (this.props.userId !== nextProps.userid) {
        this.props.getUser(nextProps.userId);
      }
    }

    render() {
      if (this.props.loading) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
      }

      return <div>{this.user.firstName}</div>
    }
  }
```

It is not a full working example. Let's imagine that `getUser` dispatch Redux action and Redux assign to the component `user`, `loading` and `getUser` props.

Answer (score 1):

It 'serves' as an opportunity to react to the incoming props to set the state of your application before render. If your call setState after render you will re-render infinitely and that's why you're not allowed to do that, so you can use componentWillReceiveProps instead.

**But...** you are beyond CORRECT in your confusion, so correct in fact that they are deprecating it and other Will-lifecycle hooks [Discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7671) [Deprecation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod/pull/195/files#diff-482f80e65f1c0ed0e031c01f4fbd0ad0).

- There are other ways to accomplish what you want to do without most of those Will-lifecycle methods, one way being don't call setState after render, just use the new incoming props directly in render (or wherever) to create the stateful value you need and then just use the new value directly, you can then later set state to keep a reference for the next iteration ex: `this.state.someState = someValue`, this will accomplish everything and not re-render the component in an infinite loop.

Comment: See also: [Documentation for `componentWillReceiveProps()` is confusing](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3610) ;)

Answer (score 0):

> changes in props of that component (inside parent render) will trigger the re-render of this child component

You are absolutely right. You only need to use this method if you need to react to those changes. For instance, you might have a piece of state in a child component that is calculated using multiple props.

Small Example:

```
class Test extends Component {
    state = {
        modified: "blank"
    };
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            modified: `${this.props.myProp} isModified`
        });
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            modified: `${nextProps.myProp} isModified`
        });
    }
    render() {
        return <div className="displayed">{this.state.modified}</div>
    }
}
```

In this example, `componentDidMount` sets the state using `this.props`. When this component receives new props, without `componentWillReceiveProps`, `this.state.modified` would never be updated again.

Of course, you could just do `{this.props.myProp + "IsModified"}` in the render method, but `componentWillReceiveProps` is useful when you need to update `this.state` on prop changes.

Answer (score 0):

> Use this as an opportunity to react to a prop transition before render() is called by updating the state using this.setState(). The old props can be accessed via this.props. Calling this.setState() within this function will not trigger an additional render.

Look at this [article](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/component_will_receive_props.html)

Answer (score 0):

the `componentWillReceiveProps` will always receive as param "`NxtProps`", `componentWillReceiveProps` is called after `render()`.

some people use this method use this to compare `nxtProps` and `this.props` to check, if something should happen before the component call `render`, and to some validations.

check the react's documentation to know more about react lifecycle!

hope this could help you!